# How to get the arguments of an instance of a Scheme define-type?

Tags: scheme, racket, plai

I have a stripped-down `define-type` of a function definition:

```
(define-type FunDef
    (fundef (fn-name symbol?)))
```

Here is a function definition which satisfies the `define-type`:

```
(fundef 'f)
```

How do I get the name of the function? For the example I gave, how to get `'f`?

I tried these and they don't work:

```
(second (fundef 'f))
(second (list (fundef 'f)))
(second '(fundef 'f))
```

What is the correct way to get the name of the function?

**Update**

I tried the suggestion to "deconstruct it with type-case". Here's what I tried:

```
(define (fundef-fun-name fundef)
    (type-case FunDef fundef
        [fundef (fn-name) 
            fn-name]))
```

That generated this error message:

```
string:3:9: type-case: this is not a variant of the specified type
```

If I understand that error message, it is saying that `fundef (fn-name)` is not correct. It appears to me to be correct. What am I missing?

Comment: What Racket `#lang` are you using? There's multiple different `define-type`s out there.

Comment: I start up racket this way: racket -I plai

Comment: You deconstruct it with `type-case`. See chapter 1 in PLAI.

Comment: Thanks @molbdnilo for the excellent suggestion. I gave your suggestion a try (see update above) but am still not getting the desired function name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a naming issue – the procedure parameter can't have the same name as the `fundef` variant.
Also, reusing the name "fn-name" in the matched pattern is a bit confusing.

Here is a working example:

```
(define (fundef-fun-name fun)
    (type-case FunDef fun
        [fundef (name) 
            name]))
```